# Android 11: How/where to write mixed media files that should survive uninstall

Tags: android, android-camera, storage, mediastore, android-external-storage

I am writing a specific use-case camera app that targets Android 11. When I hit record I would like to create a new directory somewhere (with a name based on the timestamp etc) that contains the resulting video as well as a whole heap of other custom YAML/JSON/CSV files that also get written during the recording process (belongs logically to the "output" of the recording).

I would like all of the generated files to survive an app uninstall/reinstall as I do not want to risk users losing everything they've ever recorded if they uninstall the app. How do I do this with the new scoped storage changes etc in Android 11?

Looking at the overview [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage), I can see that:

- *App-specific files*, *App preferences* and *Database* are clearly not suitable as amongst other things these files do not survive an uninstall
- *Documents and other files* uses the Storage Access Framework, but this is not suitable because it requires a system file picker every time you want to write something. This would disrupt the flow of recording/user experience, and no camera app works like that.
- *Datasets/BlobStoreManager* ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared)) also is not appropriate for my use case.
- *MediaStore API* looks like it should be the one, but it can't seem to do what I want in terms of producing a whole directory of outputs, including custom YAML/JSON/CSV text files, that all belong together. My aim is that the user at all times can simply go to the file explorer, navigate to the appropriate folder, and just copy out the folder(s) with the recordings to their computer or whatever, to save/view the data. Even MediaStore.Files does not seem to guarantee you can actually do that if your app is using scoped storage.

The only option that seems to be left is using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and putting the data wherever I want in the home directory, but that seems like a bit of an extreme permission to be asking for just in order to be able to save some text files along with my produced videos. Also, that permission is Android 11 specific. If I want to support older Android versions, what would I need to do?

What is my best choice here? Is there an option I've missed?

Comment: MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is also very undesirable because of this: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access-google-play

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but this is not suitable because it requires a system file picker every time you want to write something

No.

Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to let the user pick a document tree. In there, you can create your own sub-tree and put your own documents into that sub-tree. You do not need the "system file picker" for anything beyond the initial `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` request itself. And the resulting documents will survive an uninstall.

Comment: Am I understanding right that the app only needs to let the user pick a document tree once ever? Or does the user need to pick the document tree once per app run? Once per app update? Once per app reinstall?

Comment: Just only once. And one==one.

Comment: @pallgeuer: You will need to re-request the tree if your app is uninstalled and reinstalled. There are edge cases where you will need to re-request a tree, such as if the user deletes the original tree. Otherwise, if you use `takePersistableUriPermission()`, you will have durable access to the tree.

Comment: @CommonsWare, is there a working codes sample for write a file in external storage and  then read the file from that location  for all api including android 11 ? and an additional question for reading that document If I have to ask the user everytime ? or once ? how's the method ?

Answer (score -2):

You can create your own directory in a public directory like DCIM, Pictures, Music or Movies with classic File methods.

Comment: Yes, but unless I'm mistaken, like I said, that requires the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, which is not an option: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9956427

Comment: No. That does not require that. And why didnt you not try yet?

Comment: Yes I did, and like clearly documented in the Android documentation, the classic file write attempt fails (with EPERM operation not permitted). That only leaves the option of adding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to hope it works, and if you read the documentation you can see: _"if your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher, the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission doesn't have any effect on your app's access to storage."_ Maybe you didn't know that things have changed in Android 11?

Comment: Show your code. You cannot create files in those directories under Android 11. But you can create your own folder there and then you can create files in your folder. We do not know what you did. You need the usual permissions as before Android 10.

Comment: I used `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(...)` to get the DCIM directory (this is deprecated - how to replace?) then File::mkdir to create a folder in DCIM. That worked. Creating a FileWriter to a file in that path fails with `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/blah/stuff.yaml: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)` where I checked in a file manager that the blah folder did indeed exist from the previous `mkdir`. Just to be sure, I also tried after successfully applying the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to my app (I tapped allow).

Comment: Thus, if you have any code that successfully does what you claim is possible (tested under Android 11) then please do post it for the benefit of the community!

Comment: The exact same code I tried works completely fine if the app has the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, so it's definitely not a typo in the code. But having that permission for an app like mine is not possible with Google's new policy.

Comment: Try /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/blah/stuff.jpg as not all file tipes are allowed in DCIM.

Comment: Using your own folder in the Documents directory you can write *.yaml files. You should try and test more!

Comment: "Testing" is not a synonym for "guessing fragile undocumented behaviour", nor should it be. In any case, I can confirm jpg in a subfolder of DCIM worked and yaml in a subfolder of Documents worked. Nonetheless, it would be ill-advised to rely on such undocumented behaviour in a serious app that wants to be maintainable over the years.